# Isometric Camera Angle Changed When Running On Phone

Tags: unity, camera

I want to make an isometric camera for my game, I did it by parenting the camera to an empty object, then adjusting the rotation. It works perfectly in Unity, where the game view shows exactly what I wanted.
However, when I built and installed it on my phone, the camera is always top-down, making everything looks flat and don't have the slightly-tilted effect I wanted.

I wish to know what caused the difference in both camera views, and how to make it work as intended. Note that I want an isometric camera effect so that every game object appears as having the same angle towards my camera.

[image: Expected View (In Unity Game View)]

[image: Actual View (On phone)]

Comment: Have you tried tilting the empty object so that it would always be facing the angle you want it to?

Comment: These screenshots look like the same camera angle to me, but in the first screenshot you have shadows and in the second you don't. Try editing your question to show us a full Minimal Complete Verifiable Example - every single bit of scene setup a reader would need to replicate in their own new empty project to reproduce this problem.